# Embedded SWF posted on FB wall won't appear on new Facebook UI

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have found thousands of solutions for embedding a flash player in a Facebook wall, most of them considerably outdated and almost nothing posted after the major UI changes that FB has made relatively recently.

That being said, the most simple and (theoretically) still valid way for doing this that I've found is through posting a link that points to an HTML which presents the Open Graph tags that FB would read and interpret, as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>My title!</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="My title!">
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.com/url/">
<meta property="og:description" content="content description">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/URL_THUMBNAIL.jpeg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mysite.com">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://mysite.com/flash.swf?flashVar=0101">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="300">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="200">
```

It is important to note that the *flashVar* is necessary for the kind of application I am using, and I wouldn't expect that to be the problem, as it isn't pointed out as so when I use Facebook's object debugger (developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Furthermore, the most intriguing problem is that this solution actually **works** when I post the link with an account that still uses the old Facebook interface (without Graph Search) - a little "play" button will appear [as shown on the following link] on the thumbnail and, when I click on it, the SWF starts to play *on my Facebook wall*.

http://das.ufsc.br/~alexandrec/SSoldFB.png

However, when I try to post **the same link** on my FB account (which already has the Graph Search and all the other UI changes), this play button won't appear [as shown below] and, if I try to click on the thumbnail, another window will open with the link specified on `og:url`

http://das.ufsc.br/~alexandrec/SSnewFB.png

I am wondering if this is a matter of having my website put on some sort of white list, but I haven't found any up-to-date documentation that mentions an actual list of this kind - and as my link works on the old UI I believe I would already be on that list.

There is another way for posting SWF files on the wall through the Graph API, making a POST request of an object with a *source*, a *message* and so on, but I find this way not so interesting as I can't specify the width and height of the embedded player and that is pretty essencial for my application.

Anyone knows why this happens? Has Facebook decided that it won't allow users to post SWFs anymore, or is this just a (hopefully temporary) Facebook bug? Is there any other way to make this work (taking into consideration my necessity for defining height and width of the embedded player)?