# Facebook: post on behalf of User, share custom designed content

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read through [facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview/) and I've seen some examples on the webs, but I can't fully understand the process involved in posting content on the users timeline.

I want to connect the account of my users (users of a web application, which allows to manage and visualize some media content on a custom flash player) to Facebook, and whenever they want, let them share into their own timelines a "story" about the project they've just created.

In particular, I want to show on their timelines the flash player, and other HTML+CSS+JS content and/or interactions. 
Something like "***user*** has **created** a **project** on **MyAPP**" and then show a summary of that project on the timeline. 
(I have already done something similar using only open graph meta tags and a URL that embeds a fully interactive flash player into the timeline, [just like a youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228097/embedded-swf-posted-on-fb-wall-wont-appear-on-new-facebook-ui))

I read through [collections](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/), actions, stories and other stuff, but I still don't know:

1. Is it possible to do this: share on behalve of the user, custom tailored content? Like custom HTML + CSS + JS (and Flash) ??
2. If the above is possible, what, nn general lines, must be done to accomplish it? Create a **Facebook App, create custom actions, stories, collections, objects**... ??
3. The picture bellow is what [RunKeeper](http://runkeeper.com/) posts on my timeline after each of my runs. Is this graph something standard, made by Facebook? Or Runkeeper itself designs, creates and posts the content explicitly that way for their users ??

[image: runkeeper graph that gets posted on my timeline each time I go out for a run]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this: share on behalve of the user, custom tailored content? Like custom HTML + CSS + JS (and Flash) ??

No, of course you can not embed custom HTML and CSS – since this would not be sandboxed by browsers, you could potentially alter the whole page (think about absolute/fixed positioning, etc.), way to dangerous to allow that.

Flash can be embedded in certain ways – either custom video players for objects of the `video` type, or previews of flash-based games in the feed (keyword: feed gaming).

> The picture bellow is what RunKeeper posts on my timeline after each of my runs. Is this graph something standard, made by Facebook?

That is a story generated for the [fitness.runs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/fitness.runs) action and the [fitness.unit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/fitness.unit) object type. These are a common action and common object provided by Facebook, and they have the according story type layout pre-setup as well.

> If the above is possible, what, nn general lines, must be done to accomplish it?

That question is too broad and general to be answered here. Read the Open Graph documentation, guides and how-tos more thoroughly – and then try stuff out and see what you get.